# Generate a row for each xml element

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a requirement to break down an XML file in a flat file where each element needs to be mapped to a separate row.
Let me give an example:

Input File:

```
<Message>
<Transfer>
        <CFlow_no>1111</CFlow_no>
        <EXEName>CFLOPROJ</EXEName>
        <Entity>STCL</Entity>
        <CParty>Bulgaria</CParty>
        <CCY>BGN</CCY>
        <Deal_DT>24-Jun-2019</Deal_DT>
        <Amount>135.00</Amount>
</Transfer>
<Transfer>
        <CFlow_no>1112</CFlow_no>
        <EXEName>CFLOPROJ</EXEName>
        <Entity>STCL</Entity>
        <CParty>Bulgaria</CParty>
        <CCY>BGN</CCY>
        <Deal_DT>25-Jun-2019</Deal_DT>
        <Amount>125.00</Amount>
</Transfer>
</Message>
```

Output File:

```
CFlow_no=1111 
EXEName=CFLOPROJ
Entity=STCL                     
CParty=Bulgaria
CCY=BGN
Deal_DT=24-Jun-2019
Amount=135.00
$DoMenu = moprojected
CFlow_no=1112
EXEName=CFLOPROJ
Entity=STCL                     
CParty=Bulgaria
CCY=BGN
Deal_DT=25-Jun-2019
Amount=125.00
$DoMenu = moprojected
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: While asking a question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tried to implement it.
(3) Desired output.
(4) XSLT processor and its compliance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, or 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it is XSLT 1.0

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/Message">
        <xsl:for-each select="Transfer/*">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(local-name(),'=', .)"/>
            <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:if test="local-name()='Amount'">
                <xsl:text>$DoMenu = moprojected</xsl:text>
                <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```